# jQuery AJAX Post - Greater than conditional not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, vbulletin

I have this problem with a conditional in this code.
The code works fine except for the line.

```
<if condition="$show['member']">
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$("#submitbutton$post[postid]").click(function() {
var username = $("#username_$post[postid]").val();
var reputationamount = $("#amount_$post[postid]").val();
var dataString = 'username='+ username + '&reputationamount=' + reputationamount;

if(username == '' || reputationamount == '') {

$('.errorsameuser_$post[postid]').hide();
$('.errorreputation_$post[postid]').hide();
$('.errorempty_$post[postid]').fadeIn(200);


} else if (username == '$bbuserinfo[username]') {

$('.errorempty_$post[postid]').hide();
$('.errorreputation_$post[postid]').hide();
$('.errorsameuser_$post[postid]').fadeIn(200);

} else if (reputationamount >= '$bbuserinfo[reputation]' || reputationamount <= '0') {

$('.errorempty_$post[postid]').hide();
$('.errorsameuser_$post[postid]').hide();
$('.errorreputation_$post[postid]').fadeIn(200);

} else {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "donaterep.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(){
$('.errorempty_$post[postid]').hide();
$('.errorsameuser_$post[postid]').hide();
$('.errorreputation_$post[postid]').hide();
$('#donaterepbox_$post[postid]').fadeOut();
$('.success_$post[postid]').fadeIn(500);
}
});
} 
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

This part isn't working:

else if (reputationamount > '$bbuserinfo[reputation]' || reputationamount <= '0') {

```
$('.errorempty_$post[postid]').hide();
$('.errorsameuser_$post[postid]').hide();
$('.errorreputation_$post[postid]').fadeIn(200);

}
```

reputationamount = What the user inputs. (Example: 5)
$bbuserinfo[reputation] = The number of rep points of the person giving donation. (Example: 4)

So let's say it's..

if(5 > 4 || 5 <= '0') {

$('.errorreputation_$post[postid]').fadeIn(200);

}

It should throw that error, but instead it runs the ajax post.

Help?

The other conditionals work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because both sides of the comparison(`<`) operator are string, if one side of the operator is a number then javascript will convert the other side also to a number before the comparison is performed

Try

```
} else if (reputationamount >= $bbuserinfo[reputation] || reputationamount <= 0) {
```

Comment: @suhail in both cases one side is a number try `'5' < '25'` instead of `5 < '25'` or `'5' < 25`

Comment: @Arun P Johny - Thank you so much, that solved it, will mark the answer solved when I can! :)

Comment: @user2041167 you can also read about type conversion rules http://es5.github.io/x9.html